# Firmware-Mod-Kit Increases Size

Tags: firmware

I love using [firmware-mod-kid](https://code.google.com/p/firmware-mod-kit/) to modify SoHo router firmware.  The problem I encounter is that it often bloats the size of the image.  It appears this happens during the `mksquashfs` step.

If I'm just unsquashing a filesystem and then resquashing it with the same compression, with no modifications, why is the resulting image larger than the original?

Comment: Do you have an exact example to share of this happening?  It would be easier to analyze the before and after images rather than making blind guesses.

Comment: You're totally right, I do but not with me.  I was hoping someone else had experienced this before and just knew... I'll post the firmware image I had problems with ASAP. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is possible padding, try adding the -nopad option, assuming that you are using the same compression method.